# Data fetch from api works with https api but not with http api

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I am working on an application and made I had to make an API get request and show the data in `RecyclerView`(I used retrofit for the purpose) When I finished the code, I found that the data fetch is working fine with `HTTPS APIs` but when I put a `HTTP API` in my `BASE_URL` it doesn't work.

The following API is the one with which it works fine:
https://demonuts.com/Demonuts/JsonTest/Tennis/json_parsing.php

But using an `HTTP API`, output doesn't show up.

MainActivity

```java
package com.example.parsaniahardik.json_recycler_retrofit;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.scalars.ScalarsConverterFactory;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RetrofitAdapter retrofitAdapter;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler);

        fetchJSON();

    }

    private void fetchJSON(){

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(RecyclerInterface.JSONURL)
                .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        RecyclerInterface api = retrofit.create(RecyclerInterface.class);

        Call<String> call = api.getString();

        call.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
                Log.i("Responsestring", response.body().toString());
                //Toast.makeText()
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    if (response.body() != null) {
                        Log.i("onSuccess", response.body().toString());

                        String jsonresponse = response.body().toString();
                        writeRecycler(jsonresponse);

                    } else {
                        Log.i("onEmptyResponse", "Returned empty response");//Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Nothing returned",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void writeRecycler(String response){

        try {
            //getting the whole json object from the response
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
            if(obj.optString("status").equals("true")){

                ArrayList<ModelRecycler> modelRecyclerArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
                JSONArray dataArray  = obj.getJSONArray("data");

                for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.length(); i++) {

                    ModelRecycler modelRecycler = new ModelRecycler();
                    JSONObject dataobj = dataArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    modelRecycler.setName(dataobj.getString("name"));
                    modelRecycler.setCountry(dataobj.getString("country"));
                    modelRecycler.setCity(dataobj.getString("city"));

                    modelRecyclerArrayList.add(modelRecycler);

                }

                retrofitAdapter = new RetrofitAdapter(this,modelRecyclerArrayList);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(retrofitAdapter);
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));

            }else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, obj.optString("message")+"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Adapter

```java
public class RetrofitAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RetrofitAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ArrayList<ModelRecycler> dataModelArrayList;

    public RetrofitAdapter(Context ctx, ArrayList<ModelRecycler> dataModelArrayList){

        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(ctx);
        this.dataModelArrayList = dataModelArrayList;
    }

    @Override
    public RetrofitAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.retro_item, parent, false);
        MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view);

        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RetrofitAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {


        holder.name.setText(dataModelArrayList.get(position).getName());
        holder.country.setText(dataModelArrayList.get(position).getCountry());
        holder.city.setText(dataModelArrayList.get(position).getCity());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dataModelArrayList.size();
    }

    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView country, name, city;


        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            country = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.country);
            name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            city = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.city);
    }

    }
}
```

ApiInterface

```java
public interface RecyclerInterface {

    String JSONURL = "https://demonuts.com/Demonuts/JsonTest/Tennis/";

    @GET("json_parsing.php")
    Call<String> getString();
}
```

ModelClass

```java
public class ModelRecycler {

    private String name, country, city;



    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }
}
```

I want hat my API fetch works with both `HTTPS APIs` and also `HTTP APIs`

Comment: Are you using Android Pie to test that out? If so, TLS is enabled by default which means you can only use HTTPS. If you want to allow cleartext connection (HTTP), check the link: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/04/protecting-users-with-tls-by-default-in.html

Comment: I was indeed using Android 9 to test. It worked now. I had to make clearTrafficPermitted to true through and xml file name as network_security_config and include my Subdomain in it. And include that xml in my manifests. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: 
As mentioned by @DEVV911, this problem is encountered if you are testing the app on Android 9(Pie).
If you encounter the same problem then just make a new Android Resource Directory in the res folder and name it "xml" with resource type XML. In the "xml" folder make a new XML resource file by the name of "network_security_config". Inside it type this

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">YourDomainName.com</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

After this go to your manifest file and inside the application tag type:

```xml
<android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
```

And then it works fine.